# Lag Function in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement as below.

| PRODUCT_ID | SHIPMENT_YEAR | SHIPMENT | RETURN_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,016 | 140,464 | 2449 |
| 1 | 2,017 | 358,210 | 7433 |
| 1 | 2,018 | 14,299 | 798 |
| 1 | 2,019 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 2,020 | 11 | 0 |
| 1 | 2,021 | 15 | 0 |
| 1 | 2,022 | 1 | 0 |

The expected output is as below.

| PRODUCT_ID | SHIPMENT_YEAR | SHIPMENT (C) | RETURN_QTY (D) | Effective Return Qty (E) | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,016 | 140,464 | 2,449 | 138,015 | C3 - D3 |
| 1 | 2,017 | 358,210 | 7,433 | 488,792 | E3 + C4 - D4 |
| 1 | 2,018 | 14,299 | 798 | 502,293 | E4 + C5 - D5 |
| 1 | 2,019 | 12 | 1 | 502,304 | E5 + C6 - D6 |
| 1 | 2,020 | 11 | 0 | 502,315 | E6 + C7 - D7 |
| 1 | 2,021 | 15 | 0 | 502,330 | E7 + C8 - D8 |
| 1 | 2,021 | 1 | 0 | 502,331 | E8 + C9 - D9 |

The column formula is to show how column E is derived.

Please help me to get above output using Snowflake query

Comment: Please don’t link to images in your question, add all information directly in your question, preferably as editable text

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use LAG, but can use a [WINDOW FUNCTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html) on SUM, which allows you to accumulate a sum over the rows. Which is what you sre trying todo.

```
SELECT 
    product_id,
    shipment_year,
    shipment,
    return_qty,
    SUM( shipment - return_qty ) OVER (ORDER BY shipment_year) AS big_sum
FROM VALUES
    (1,2016,140464,2449),
    (1,2017,358210,7433),
    (1,2018,14299,798),
    (1,2019,12,1),
    (1,2020,11,0)
    t(product_id, shipment_year, shipment, return_qty);
```

| PRODUCT_ID | SHIPMENT_YEAR | SHIPMENT | RETURN_QTY | BIG_SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,016 | 140,464 | 2,449 | 138,015 |
| 1 | 2,017 | 358,210 | 7,433 | 488,792 |
| 1 | 2,018 | 14,299 | 798 | 502,293 |
| 1 | 2,019 | 12 | 1 | 502,304 |
| 1 | 2,020 | 11 | 0 | 502,315 |